# Terminal process was terminated with exit code 1

Tags: git

I am trying to deploy my project to git pages, but I ran into a problem with publication.

When I use the command:

`git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git master`

where USERNAME is my username on GitHub, I get an error:

> Terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bit\bash.exe `--login`" was terminated with exit code 1.

What advice can you give?

Comment: Go through the setup step by step. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/set-up-git specifically the section called "Next steps: Authenticating with GitHub from Git"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to push with ssh when I did not have the ssh key on my github account. If you want to push with https you need the https url from your repo > code > HTTPS.